# How to plot contour of FFT of an image in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fft, contour

I want to know how to plot the contour of the FFT of an image in Matlab. I have this code but when plotting the contour I get a blue plot. I think I need to specify the range of the frequencies in the contour function, but how to know/compute the range?

```
monolayer = double(imread('TEM_monolayer_graphene.bmp'));
monolayerFFTs = fftshift(fft2(monolayer));
contour(monolayerFFTs);
```

I think instead of the blue plot I should get a 3D plot with some spikes at the frequencies where there is more energy.

[image: Current contour plot of FFT2D]

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13549186/

Comment: Do you mind sharing your image so that we can see what's going on there?

Comment: @BRabbit27 is that the plot of the raw data (TEM_monolayer_graphene.bmp) or the plot of the contour?

Comment: Is the contour. Is the output I get when executing the code above.

Comment: You need to take the magnitude of the output from the Fourier transform, using the `abs` function, just as is explained in the question linked by nkjt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get a really good plot with the following code

```
monolayer = double(imread('TEM_monolayer_graphene.bmp'));
monolayerFFTs = fftshift(fft2(monolayer));
contour(abs(monolayerFFTs));
```