# Plotting phase and magnitude image Fourier

Tags: image, matlab, plot, fft, phase

How can I plot phase and magnitude of Fourier transform of a 2D image in MATLAB?
I am using `angle` and `abs` and then use `imshow`, but I get a black image.
what is the use of `fftshift` in this plotting?

Comment: try imagesc(abs(fftshift(fft2(I))));

Comment: I tried this but it only display a black image with a white point in the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
F = fft2(I); where I is the input
F = fftshift(F); % Center FFT

F = abs(F); % Get the magnitude
F = log(F+1); % Use log, for perceptual scaling, and +1 since log(0) is undefined
F = mat2gray(F); % Use mat2gray to scale the image between 0 and 1

imshow(F,[]); % Display the result
```

Try this. Code taken from:[How to plot a 2D FFT in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13549186/how-to-plot-a-2d-fft-in-matlab)

Comment: I've seen this gode but I didn't understand why we use log and fftshift why we didn't just show that without using this?

Comment: Thanks lakesh you saved me! I've spent Hours searching for that log(F+1) :D
Here is a clarification to be in safe side when you prepare the input I if you read it by f = imread(imPath); you will need this F = fft2(double(f)); as the image has been read in unit8 format so they should be converted to double arrays before doing the FFTs. 
Quoted from http://matlabgeeks.com/tips-tutorials/how-to-do-a-2-d-fourier-transform-in-matlab/#comment-5137

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, you need to remove the DC offset.
Something like:

```
imagesc(abs(fftshift(fft2(I - mean(I(:))))));
```